# Code for Cross Validation

Tags: r, validation

Could someone please validate the algorithm for 10 fold cross validation?

I do not want to use the cut function as I thought of this intuition

1) Find length of the dataframe, n.
2) No: instances in test set `size = floor(n/10)`
3) loop over i from 1:10
4) Create folds by taking the indices;
  a) `indices=1:size` of the data frame for first fold
  b) `indices=((i - 1) * size + 1):(i * size)` for all the other folds except the         10th 
  c) `indices=((i - 1) * size + 1):(n)` for the 10th fold

```
  test=df[indices,]
  train=df[-indices,]
```

5) Train the model and find the MSE for each fold.

Comment: You need [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the Caret package. It automatically divides datasets into training and testing. See here:

[Caret Package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html)

Example:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(325)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(df$"Yourdata", p = .5, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)
```

The `p value` is the percentage of the data that goes to training.

The `times value`specifies how many partitions you want to create.

The `createFolds` command of the Caret package can be used to create balanced cross validation groupings.